# SSIS File System task

Tags: ssis

I have a file system task that copies files from one folder into another. When I execute it, I get Access to path [File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Could not find file 'C:\temp'.".

I have banged my head for 2 days with it . can you please help.

Comment: Are you running it in visual studio or on the SQL Server? Do you have a C:\temp on the sql server? Does the account it is runnign under have access to c:\temp?

Comment: I am running it under Visual Studio. It has all rights .Its actually c:\ JLR but even this has all permissions , yes it has all the acess .

Comment: The error message says "could not find *file* 'C:\temp'"   or "could not find *folder* C:\temp"?    Because it sounds like you're giving it the name of a folder where you should be specifying a file.

Comment: Hi Tab , the task is to rename all the files in directory . However there is no function , I could find for renaming in file system task

Comment: In your original question you said 'copies' now you say 'renames' - you need to get your story straight.

Answer (score -2):

You have to provide a file on that Temp folder first and prefer a different folder which is not in the C drive because C drive can restricts permissions sometimes.

Comment: permissions are permissions whether it is on c drive or not will not matter